# how do some sandwiches feel creamy

Tags: sandwich

I'm just learning to cook, I'm from India so sorry if my question is too stupid.
I made a sandwich following the recipe given on some blogs, using chicken salami but my sandwich is DRY and many sandwiches I ate felt like creamy. I don't think its cheese, I mean besides cheese there is something else! How to make sandwiches like those? are there any categories of sandwiches?

Comment: In America we rely on cheese (different types), mayonnaise, mustard, ketchup, butter --- all kinds of stuff. "Dry" is generally an unacceptable term for sandwiches. But when it comes to sandwiches, there are no rules. *Anything* you might use to add moistness to *anything else* is fair game for sandwiches.

Comment: Questions are not stupid EVER just because they come from a culture other than the one(s) from which most of us come.

Comment: Thanks. I added cheese spreads, but was wondering what would normally they add other than cheese, I'll try mayonnaise next time

Comment: In my world mayo is the number 1 ingredient to make sandwiches not dry. Please do not let that stifle your creativity. If something else tickles your brain as an idea, *try it*.

Comment: Besides the recommendation for condiments to add moisture, you should also look at your bread selection.  It won't necessarily make the difference of a 'creamy' sandwich, but will prevent it from being overly 'dry'.  Enriched breads (with egg & sugar) tend to be more moist, as do other softer breads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no official categories of sandwiches, although there are considerable regional differences in what is considered a "prototypical" sandwich across the world (and some cultures have multiple common sandwiches). A traditional American sub is very different from a German Käsebrot. So, I can't point you to a type of sandwich and tell you "it will always be creamy".

There are two things which you can use to make a sandwich creamy.

- Spread butter or cream cheese on the bread before adding the toppings. It will give the sandwich a nice, mild taste, and remove the dry mouthfeel, without making it very moist.
- Use a condiment. Typical sandwich condiments are mustard, mayonnaise and ketchup. They make a sandwich very moist and creamy, and tend to also give it a strong taste. They are normally placed between the toppings, not on the bread, so they don't soak into the bread and make it soggy.

My suggestion is to try out both variants and decide which you like best.

Comment: Thanks, last time I spread thin layer of butter on one side and cheese on the other. But nothing between the toppings. Will try with mayonnaise or mustard between the topping next.

Comment: Mayo is often spread on the bread. At least here...

Comment: I agree with @derobert. It sounds to me as though you had sandwhiches with mayonnaise on them.

Comment: Ketchup tends to be *too* wet for a good sandwich ... unless you're using a roll (and not bread slices), you risk it soaking through the bread.  Sugary or oily condiments (eg, chutney, pesto, tapanade, mayo) tend to be better than overly wet ones for sliced bread.  Mustard is strong enough that it's used sparingly, so doesn't suffer from the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try mayonnaise (aka "mayo" in American English). I use Hellman's, which I think is better quality.

When making the sandwich, first begin by spreading mayonnaise on the sandwich bread that you use, before adding the meat. I would suggest starting with a little mayonnaise - then increase the amount of mayonnaise to your taste.

I hope this info helps you to find that "creamy" consistency that you are trying to duplicate in your sandwiches.